# How to get the Username only the characters not the whitespaces?

Tags: java, jsp

In jsp application, i am checking username and password, when entering whitespace in username means it didnt show the error, how to validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you do it in the back end, you can use a javascrit regex :

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+@){0,1}([a-zA-Z0-9.])+$
```

This will permit A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and ., and at most one @

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to `trim()` the value before checking the username/password:

```
String password = getPassword().trim();
```

This will remove all leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: What happen, if the user put a white space in between the username?

Comment: Like "user name" instead of "username"? That is, by general convention, an illegal entry. No one expects that a server will correct it magically.

Comment: So, That is why a client side validation needed...?

Comment: I wouldn't care about that at the client side. I'd send anything the user enters to the server and let the server decide, whether the entered String is a valid username or not. My only server-side service: trimming to remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Do a regex validation, if your username contains only digits and alphabets, do something like

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Change it based on length limitations

Answer (score 0):

You have two different questions:

1. > **How to get the Username only the characters not the whitespaces?**

   To do that, you can simply replace all the whitespaces in your string:

   ```
   String name = " blah is a word";
   name = name.replace(" ", "");
   ```
2. > **How to validate the username?**

   To do that, you can simply check if the string contains a whitespace.

   ```
   String name = " blah is a word";
   if (name.contains(" "))
   {
       // Wrong
   } else
   {
       // Correct
   }
   ```